# Unable to assign value to label in controller before displayed?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Guys this has been doing my head in for hours .... :(

I have an array of controllers which are loaded into a scrollview

I want to assign values to a Label 'Category' but I am unable to do this - The value is shown as NULL ??

I can however hard code this in the method viewDidLoad?

I've tried a couple of approaches but none work? ...

My .h file looks like this...

```
@interface ReviewCategoryViewController : UIViewController {
    @public
    UILabel *CategoryTitle;
}

- (id)initWithCategory:(NSString *)category;
- (id)setCategory:(NSString *)category;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *CategoryTitle;

@end
```

My implementation looks like this ...

```
- (id)setCategory:(NSString *)category
{
    [self.CategoryTitle setText:category];
    NSLog(@">>2. Category %@ %@", category, CategoryTitle.text);

    return self;
}

// load the view nib and initialize the pageNumber ivar
- (id)initWithCategory:(NSString *)category
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:@"ReviewCategoryViewController" bundle:nil];

    [self.CategoryTitle setText:category];
    NSLog(@">>1. Category %@ %@", category, CategoryTitle.text);

    return self;
}
```

My call of the method looks like this...

```
    ReviewCategoryViewController *controller = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:cardNo];

    if ((NSNull *)controller == [NSNull null])
    {
        NSString *temp = [categories_array objectAtIndex:cardNo];

        controller = [[ReviewCategoryViewController alloc] initWithCategory:temp];

        [controller setCategory:temp];

        [viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:cardNo withObject:controller];
    }
```

My log shows the following ????

```
2013-04-12 16:54:27.507 Review Writer[14455:11603] >>1. Category Adapability **(null)**
2013-04-12 16:54:27.509 Review Writer[14455:11603] >>2. Category Adapability **(null)**
```

Comment: are you sure you linked your label in Interface Builder? Try printing NSLog(@">>1. Category %@ %@", category, CategoryTitle); to see if it is linked properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set category in global var and set labe text in didLoad method:

```
- (id)initWithCategory:(NSString *)category
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:@"ReviewCategoryViewController" bundle:nil];

    // categoryStr is a global NSString var
    categoryStr = category;

    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self.CategoryTitle setText:categoryStr];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (id)initWithCategory:(NSString *)category
{
    seidlf = [super initWithNibName:@"ReviewCategoryViewController" bundle:nil];

    [self.CategoryTitle setText:category];
    NSLog(@">>1. Category %@ %@", category, CategoryTitle.text);

    return self;
}
```

After calling `self = [super initWithNibName:@"ReviewCategoryViewController" bundle:nil];` the links to your outlet is not yet established yet. You can only use your outlets after the view is loaded in `viewDidLoad` method;